# How to retrieve the complete key from the returned object of an ancestor query in google datastore?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using ancestor query to retrieve the entity from google datastore using nodejs

`query = datastore.createQuery(entity).hasAncestor(key)`

where the key is

`key = datastore.key([kind_name_of_parent, id_of_parent])`

I am able to retrieve the objects but i would like to get the complete key of the retrieved object, whereas the returned array only contains the returned objects and the endCursor.

> How can i get the complete key? or, can i get the complete key
>   from the endCursor?

An example for my query result is:

`[{ modTS: 1481006473081,
    modLoc: null,
    modUid: 0,
    createTS: 1481006473081 } ], 
{ moreResults: 'NO_MORE_RESULTS',
  endCursor: 'CloSVGoTc350ZXN0cHJvamVjdC0zN2ZiNnI9CxIEdXNlchiAgID409OICgw‌​LEgRzaW1zGICAgICAgIA‌​KDAsSDmNsaWVudFNldHR‌​wsdrfGICAgICA5NEKDBg‌​AIAA=' } ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since datastore client [v0.42.2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/releases/tag/v0.42.2) the key is now referred using a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) on the datastore client [`datastoreClient.KEY`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/0.5.1/datastore?method=KEY).

Run this on the CLI, if it doesn't work the first time run it again (first time might fail because of 'eventual consistency').

```
'use strict';

const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore'),
    projectId = 'your-project-id',
    datastore = Datastore({
        projectId: projectId
    }),
    pkind = 'Foo',
    pname = 'foo',
    kind = 'Bar',
    name = 'bar',
    parentKey = datastore.key([pkind, pname ]),
    entityKey = datastore.key([pkind, pname, kind, name]),
    entity = {
        key: entityKey,
        data: {
            propa: 'valuea'
        }
    },
    query = datastore.createQuery().hasAncestor(parentKey).limit(5);

let complete = false;

datastore.save(entity).then(() => {
    datastore.runQuery(query).then((res) => {
        try {
            console.log('parent key ', res[0][0][datastore.KEY].parent);
        } finally {
            complete = true;
        }
    });

});

function waitUntilComplete() {
    if (!complete)
        setTimeout(waitUntilComplete, 1000);
}

waitUntilComplete();
```

Comment: res[0][datastore.KEY] is printing undefined

Comment: Which version of @google-cloud/datastore are you using? I'm using 0.5.1.

Comment: even i am using 0.5.1

Comment: You are using cursors it seems. That means your query result will be an array, the first element will be entities array, the second element is result metadata. Try res[0][0][datastore.KEY] to get the key of the first entity result.

Comment: I got the complete key. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AkashDathan I saw your edit. Did you try running it? I don't think it will work. The variable `Key` is not defined. Additionally the extra index `res[0][0][datastore.KEY]` will not work in your version because query.limit() is not being used. I did not include limit() in my original answer because you did not make it clear you were using it in your original question! :-)

Comment: @AkashDathan I improved and accepted your edit. It turns out you must be using the promise based interface instead of nodejs callback interface for runQuery to get that extra index too.

Comment: I have actually ran the code and were able to retrieve the keys, thanks to you. I had to use the command datastore.createQuery(childkey).hasAncestor(parentKey), and the results were obtained by using res[0][0][datastore.KEY]. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The latest update to the datastore SDK has changed the way keys are accessed in an entity.

Earlier the entity had a key called `key` which had a complete JSON object with information of the key.

After the update, the key is now referred using [Symbols](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_symbols.html), a new ES6 datatype.

The key will be referenced using `entity[datastoreClient.KEY]` assuming `datastoreClient` is correctly authenticated/initialised object of the datasotore SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The keys were retrieved by:
`res[0][0][datastore.KEY]`